# Update SQL column only if the value doesn't already exist in the table

Tags: sql, merge, sql-server-2012, exists

I am using SQL Server 2012 and my table's column has comma-separated values (bad practice, but unavoidable for now). Each time a user tries to add applicants, how do I check whether its already present or not, and update (append) only if its not already present.

```
JobID        Applicants
----------------------------
J001         a001,a002,a003
```

eg. if I try to add applicants a003,a004 in one go for job J001, only a004 should be appended.

I believe merge can be helpful here, but am unable to figure out how.

I tried splitting the incoming value (through USP parameter) by converting into XML, but don't know what to do now in the stored procedure.

Comment: Can you post the code to show how far you've got "so far". It'll really help people to come up with answers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses, I was able to pick up bits and pieces and get a solution I was looking for. Creating Split function helped a lot. Currently I am trying to make changes in the system to avoid comma separated values in a row, might need a minor release, but worth the pains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for your question.

Follow the below steps.

1 . create the below function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitString
(    
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

            INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
      END

      RETURN
END
GO
```

2. creating sample input table #T

   ```
   SELECT 'J001' as JobID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'a001,a002,a003') as Applicants INTO #T
   ```
3. and the below script will perform your update.

   ```
          ;with cte_1
          as
        (SELECT item  FROM #T
           cross apply (select item from dbo.SplitString(Applicants, ','))X
         WHERE JobID='J001')
        UPDATE t

        set t.Applicants= t.Applicants+','+ STUFF(( SELECT ','+b.Item  

                     FROM dbo.SplitString('a001,a002,a004,a005', ',') b
                       LEFT JOIN  cte_1 a ON b.Item=a.Item 
                       WHERE a.Item IS NULL  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '')
       FROM #T t WHERE t.JobID='J001'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You already know that this is a very bad data structure, so we don't have to go into that.  When you are stuck with such a structure, you can use string operations, but they are not particularly efficient;

My recommendation would be to add them one at a time:

```
update t
    set Applicants = (case when Applicants is not null
                           then Applicants + ',' + cast(@ApplicantId as varchar(255)
                           else cast(@ApplicantId)
                      end)
    where JobId = @JobId and
          ',' + Applicants + ',' not like '%,' + cast(@ApplicantId as varchar(255)) + '%,';
```

There is no need to compound your problem with comma-delimited lists by trying to use one for the update values as well as the stored values.

And, let me repeat, that storing values this way is a really, really bad idea in SQL and should only be supported when someone else (who doesn't know better) has forced the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you know its bad Gordon has made a point that it is bad and he gave you a way to update 1 row at a time but if you are dealing with a delimited list which is really supposed to represent table my guess is you don't want to just update 1 record at a time...

First thing is first if you have data like this get yourself a good table valued function to Split the delimited string!  here is one I just wrote not too flexible if you want a multiple character delimiter but gives you and idea.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitDelimitedString
(
    @DelimitedString VARCHAR(8000)
    ,@Delimitor CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS 
@ReturnTable TABLE (Id INT,String VARCHAR(8000))
AS
BEGIN
    IF CHARINDEX(@Delimitor,@DelimitedString) = 0
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO @ReturnTable (Id,String)
       VALUES (1,@DelimitedString)

       RETURN
    END

    ;WITH cteStrings AS (
       SELECT
          1 AS Id
          ,LEFT(@DelimitedString,CHARINDEX(@Delimitor,@DelimitedString) - 1) as String
          ,RIGHT(@DelimitedString,LEN(@DelimitedString) - CHARINDEX(@Delimitor,@DelimitedString))
             + CASE WHEN RIGHT(@DelimitedString,1) <> @Delimitor THEN @Delimitor ELSE '' END as RemainingStrings
       UNION ALL
       SELECT
          Id + 1 as Id
          ,LEFT(RemainingStrings,CHARINDEX(@Delimitor,RemainingStrings)-1) as String
          ,RIGHT(RemainingStrings,LEN(RemainingStrings) - CHARINDEX(@Delimitor,RemainingStrings)) as RemainingStrings
       FROM
          cteStrings
       WHERE
          CHARINDEX(@Delimitor,RemainingStrings) > 0
    )

    INSERT INTO @ReturnTable (Id, String)
    SELECT
       Id
       ,String
    FROM
       cteStrings

    RETURN 
END
GO
```

Next make sure you know how to re concatenate a string you split, there are lots of examples and techniques I will use the STUFF with FOR XML PATH technique. Once you have split the string you want to update you can either also split the Table with a Cross Apply using the same function or use Gordon's LIKE technique.

Here is an example using Gordon's Technique

```
DECLARE @TableA AS TABLE (JobId CHAR(4), Applicants VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TableA (JobId, Applicants) VALUES ('J001','a001,a002,a003')
DECLARE @AddApplicants VARCHAR(100) = 'a003,a004,a005,a005'
DECLARE @JobId CHAR(5) = 'J001'

SET @AddApplicants = STUFF(
       (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + String
       FROM
          dbo.SplitDelimitedString(@AddApplicants,',') a
          LEFT JOIN @TableA t
          ON t.JobId = @JobId
          AND t.Applicants LIKE '%,' + a.String + '%'
       WHERE
          t.JobId IS NULL
       FOR XML PATH(''))
    ,1,1,'')

UPDATE @TableA
    SET Applicants = CASE WHEN LEN(Applicants) > 0 THEN Applicants + ',' ELSE '' END + @AddApplicants
WHERE
    JobId = @JobId

SELECT *
FROM
    @TableA
```

And if you would rather use CROSS APPLY you could do something like this:

```
SET @AddApplicants = STUFF(
       (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + a.String
       FROM
          dbo.SplitDelimitedString(@AddApplicants,',') a
          LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT DISTINCT a.String
             FROM
                @TableA t
                CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitDelimitedString(t.Applicants,',') a
             WHERE
                t.JobId = @JobId
          ) t
          ON a.String = t.String
       WHERE
          t.String IS NULL
       FOR XML PATH(''))
    ,1,1,'')
```

Answer (score -1):

How about splitting a003,a004 and search each string with comma (eg. 'a003'||',') into the applicants field with a conditional?

I hope you find it useful.

Comment: More of a comment than a solution. This approach is possible, but how would it be done? You should improve your answer to expand on this.